# determinant properties (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I was gone the day we went over determinant properties and I'm super confused by the notes I was given. Any explanation would help!

If a $4\times 4$ matrix $A$ has $\det(A) = \frac 14$, then:

**a)** $\det(2A)=$

**b)** $\det(-A)=$

**c)** $\det(A^2)=$

**d)** $\det(A^{-1})=$

**e)** $\det(A^T)=$

Comment: So could you please post the line(s) of the notes where you have doubt?

Comment: Somewhere in you notes should be the information that det(cA)= cdet(A) for any number c, that det(A^T)= det(A), and that det (AB)= det(A) det(B) as long as A and B are square matrices of the same size.

Comment: @user247327 Note that $\det\left(cA\right)=c^n\det\left(A\right)$, and not $c\det\left(A\right)$, where $n$ is the number of rows (or columns) of $A$.

Comment: Ouch!  Thanks!  You are completely correct.

Comment: @LiChunMin I just have a bunch of examples and no actual standard identities in my notes

Comment: @KrystalRebhun That's a shame...When I study linear algebra one semester ago, we were provided with those identities with proofs, using the notion of miltilinear functions. (but we had to find examples our own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

These are all the [standard identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant_identities#Identities) you will need.
$$\det(A^T)=\det(A)$$
$$\det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(A)}$$
For an $n\times n$ matrix:
$$\det(cA)=c^n \det(A)$$
Note that determinants are [distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property). If $A$ and $B$ are the same size:
$$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$$
Therefore, for part **c)** let $A=B$.